# Launch Flutter to Specific screen from Kotlin native side plugin

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, android-intent, background-service

I have Flutter plugin

That shows fullscreen notification from background or when terminated using Push notification

This screen is built in Kotlin

and it has a button that when pressed

it launch the Main Intent of the application - the code in that plugin is the following

```
     ACTION_CALL_ACCEPT -> {
                    saveCallState(callIdToProcess!!, CALL_STATE_ACCEPTED)
    
                    channel.invokeMethod("onCallAccepted", parameters)
    
                    var launchIntent = getLaunchIntent(context!!)
                    launchIntent?.action = ACTION_CALL_ACCEPT
                    
    
                    context.startActivity(launchIntent)
                     }
```

this works fine and it launch the application to the default route

I want it to open specific screen instead , also if there is a way to pass the parameters to this screen

I don't know if this can be achieved with  `channel.invokeMethod`

because this is in the plugin side , I cannot run Navigator inside it's Dart code (NO context available there)

I only know basics of Kotlin that's why I don't know how to achieve this properly

Thanks in advance .

Comment: read https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: @JiteshMohite I read this page a lot , I implemented it inside the plugin main.dart file and managed to make it print to console when the button pressed, but I can't make it access navigator in that side.

Comment: because navigator and the main widget builder and my screens are in the main lib folder,
the plugin cannot access it.

Comment: hi @IslamAhmady i face the same issue here, do you find any solutions?

Comment: I am also struck with same problem.  I have created pinned shortcuts using Kotlin. It opens up the main app screen but not sure how to take it second screen.

Comment: gettin same issue, how can convert my widget to an intent?